# Perl code to find an array element in a sentence and then to look either side of the match for another string to be matched from a different array

Tags: regex, perl

I have 2 arrays in which one of the array consists of words which I consider as trigger words while the second array is a list of names. I want to find sentences in a file which have the trigger word and then look both right and left and find the matches using the array name.

I am kind of confused about how to go about solving this problem.

```
my @strings = (
    'SPARC is an activator of SPARCL1.',
    'SPARCL1 and SPARC regulate the expression of TGFB1.',
    'SPARCL1 and SPARC are used in signal transduction.',
    'SPARCL1 and ADAMTS4 have been found to upregulated by MMP3 and MMP3 are downregulated by SMAD3.',
);

my @trigs = ( "activator", "regulate", "upregulated" , "downregulated" );
my @genes = ( "SPARC", "SPARCL1", "ADAMTS4", "MMP3", "SMAD3", "TGFB1" );
```

Desired output:

```
SPARC is an activator of SPARCL1
SPARC regulate the expression of TGFB1
ADAMTS4 have been found to upregulated by MMP3
MMP3 are downregulated by SMAD3
```

Comment: Right TH idea was if I get a trig word I look left and right and find the first gene mention rather than first finding the gene mentions. So if I have 2 trigger words in a sentence if I find a gene right and left of the trigger word that is one phrase. for the second trigger if i find a gene left and right of it then it is good but if i don't find a gene either on the left or the right I discard it.

Comment: So basically in line 4 it becomes ADAMTS4 have been found to **upregulated** by MMP3 and MMP3 are **downregulated** by SMAD3

Comment: Well again to answer your questions 1) and 3) I am right now attempting to catch only one gene despite 2 being present. I will try to capture the first instance and not the second in both right and left. Some loss of info but that is acceptable.  so the second line should be "SPARC regulate the expression of TGFB1" 2)in line 4 once one triple of gene-trigger-gene is captured it treats the next part of the line to search for the same pattern again.

Comment: I am sorry that I haven't clear in my description. I meant was that I am not matching the period at all. My output is just the 'gene-trig-gene' matching with no concern for the occurrence of the period. I hope now I am clear.

Comment: But I I guess the solution you have given is good. Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $trig_re = join '|', map quotemeta, @trigs;
$trig_re = qr/\b(?:$trig_re)/;

my $gene_re = join '|', map quotemeta, @genes;
$gene_re = qr/\b(?:$gene_re)\b/;

my $re = qr/
   (
      $gene_re
      (?:(?!$gene_re|$trig_re).)*
      $trig_re
      (?:(?!$gene_re|$trig_re).)*
      $gene_re
   )
/sx;

for my $string (@strings) {
   say $1 while $string =~ /$re/g;
}
```

Output:

```
SPARC is an activator of SPARCL1
SPARC regulate the expression of TGFB1
ADAMTS4 have been found to upregulated by MMP3
MMP3 are downregulated by SMAD3
```

Comment: One more query. If I am looking at lists of 40000 words/phrases and about the same number of sentences is there an more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The approach taken by my solution is quite efficient (as long as you use Perl 5.10 or newer).

Comment: Just one more query, if my names have digits, will the regexp work because I have been unable to execute if the names have numbers in them like ABC1.

Comment: I edited the question with actual code I am running and the input file. This is not working and am not able to understand why.

Comment: @ary, You miscopied `(...)` into `{...}`, and I fixed the problem that caused the first line of output to be `SPARC is an activator of SPARC`.